# EF Code First seems to be crashing worker process

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I used EF Code First to initially create my database during the development stages. When I moved the project to a staging environment on a server I included a small hack to avoid altering or dropping the database when in a particular phase. (Therefore it would connect to an existing database). I have now made a simple copy of the project and am trying to host it in another location on the server to have a staging and live version running concurrently but using two different databases which I assumed could just be set in the web.config. When I run it from the one location it works but on the other location my application pool fails

```
A process serving application pool 'XYZ' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '1234'. The data field contains the error number.

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17725, time stamp: 0x4ec49b8f
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0002e04e
Faulting process id: 0x1d98
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce1b29dcf57530
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 1fd4a0b0-871d-11e2-a272-be31a5415ec8
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Details regarding the code:

**Global.asax** - Application_Start

```
if (DAL.General.Helpers.Phase == "Live") {
    Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyContextProductionInitialiser());
} else {
    Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitialiser());
}
```

**MyContextProductionInitialiser**

```
public class MyContextProductionInitialiser : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            throw new System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException("Database does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyContextInitialiser**

```
public class MyContextInitialiser : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext> {...}
```

**MyContext**

```
public MyContext() : base("name=MyContextConnectionString") {
    Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

** Web.config **

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContextConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.;Database=database_staging;User Id=sa;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient " />
</connectionStrings>
```

Database: I am using a shared SQL Login user for the staging and live databases.

Application pools: There are two separate yet identical application pools running in IIS 7.5. They are both v4.0 Integerated.

**Edit**
If I update the database name to be exactly the same as the original database name then it works. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker process is crashing because of a Stack Overflow. I am still investigating but when writing to the database, the following exception is thrown: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'XYZ'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.` The configuration of the new database's IDENTITY fields must be incorrect somehow. On an error, I write to a Error table thus resulting in the SO and the worker process crashing.

For some reason with the way SQL is configured I cannot do a simple restore of the database so I simply dropped the database and re-created it by scripting the objects and re-configured the necessary tables.

Lesson learned: if a worker process crashes, there is a good reason for it, in this case a StackOverflow makes perfect sense!